# Novel from 90s/00s about faith/music and Jesus as a musician

Tags: story-identification, novel

Trying to track down a 80s/90s novel I read in high school, and my individual efforts have hit a wall.

Main character is a guitarist/potential rock star, staunch atheist. Tension with love interest about faith/religion set up early in the book.

Main character somehow winds up in a fantasy world, where music is either rare, magical, or outlawed. At one point meets another musician that is at least heavily implied to be Jesus, if not blatantly named as such.

My brain keeps picturing a blue cover, ice/water may factor into cover design, title, or theme.